# Bootstrap Contact Form server not responding

Tags: php, contact-form

I am trying to get my contact form to work, but when I fill out the form, it throws out a server not responding error.

You can view the JSFiddle here: [JS & HTML contact form code](http://jsfiddle.net/4wLdqu6h/1/)

The contact_me.php code:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// check if fields passed are empty
if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
   empty($_POST['email'])       ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])       ||
   empty($_POST['message'])     ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
    echo "No arguments Provided!";
    return false;
   }

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

// create email body and send it    
$to = 'trisha@trishajohnson.net'; // put your email
$email_subject = "Contact form submitted by:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message. \n\n".
                  " Here are the details:\n \nName: $name \n ".
                  "Email: $email_address\n Phone: $phone\n Message: \n $message";
$headers = "From: no-reply@trishajohnson.net\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;            
?>
```

I don't see any errors in any of the code, so I'm not quite sure what the issue is.

Comment: Try adding error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` instead.

Comment: Plus, far as I can see, your form has no action (form defaults to self when omitted) and no method. Form defaults to GET when omitted.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have added the error reporting tag to my contact_me.php, and I also added action="assets/contact_me.php" to my form.. it is still not working.

Comment: Did you also add `method="post"` inside `<form>`?

Comment: @Fred-ii-, yes, `method="post"` is inside `<form>`.. I just reuploaded the files to server, refreshed page, and it seems to have sent. I checked my email, and it is there.

Comment: Your form's elements are also missing names. I.e.: `<input type="text" name="name">` - `<input type="text" name="email">` etc.

Comment: Errr... you're welcome. Usually, the person who helped you should be the one putting in an answer ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I wasn't trying to steal your thunder, I will delete the answer so that you can add it yourself if you like.

Answer (score 0):

When I visited your page, I noticed the following were missing from the form:

- The form's action. Forms default to GET when omitted.
- Missing name elements.

Solution:

- Add `method="post"` inside the form.
- Add the name attribute to the inputs, i.e.: `<input type="text" name="name">`

Your PHP contains POST variables and POST relies on the name attribute in order to process the form's data.

Sidenote: Your original question did not contain the error reporting, which should be used to check for errors.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.