# Emails not being sent from php form (Bootstrap template)

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap, email

I have been trying to get my Bootstrap php form to work for the last several hours. I've checked the answers and tried to follow the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32976876/im-not-receiving-emails-from-my-bootstrap-template-php-form), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-form-doesnt-complete-sending-e-mail) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27261939/bootstrap-contact-form-server-not-responding#) to no avail.

My contact_me.php is as follows:

```
<?php
// Check for errors
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])      ||
   empty($_POST['email'])     ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])     ||
   empty($_POST['message'])   ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
   echo "No arguments Provided!";
   return false;
   }

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'myemail@gmail.com'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from a visitor to your site.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@yourdomain.co.uk\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";   
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;         
?>
```

Submitting the form gets me the "Your message was sent." but I haven't received any emails...

Any thoughts?

(mytest@gmail.com and noreply@yourdomain.com aren't the real email addresses used, obviously heh)

Comment: this same piece of code appears often on Stack and I've lost count.

Comment: how do you return a boolean if you are not inside of a function

Comment: `if (mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers)) { echo "Mail has done its job."; } else { echo "Something went wrong and you need to find out why."; }`

Comment: Yep, that exact example was posted twice today already (with nobody bothering to mention its origin, so it could someday be fixed there instead of being discussed here daily). -- If you've seen the reference question already, then let on your mail server configuration, logs, dkim/spf records etc.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. The template source can be found here: https://github.com/IronSummitMedia/startbootstrap-agency

My error.log file isn't returning anything specific in relation to the php file, but I am seeing sh: 1: /usr/sbin/sendmail: not found

I appreciate you've seen this before but the links I've checked so far had different solutions and neither worked for me.